# Model String Field name in URL instead of id - AttributeError Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to access detail view. Previous i used id in url and it was working correctly. Now my condition has changed and instead of `id`, I want to add `place_id` in url. For that i used `<str:place_id>` but it is giving `AttributeError`. How can i add `place_id` in url and get correct data. And what is slug. Should i use it. But my `place_id` is unique.

urls.py

```
path('detail/<str:place_id>/', Detail.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

Models.py

```
class Map(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    place_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
```

Views.py

```
class Detail(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    template_name = "detail.html"
    model = Map
    context_object_name = 'map'
```

Error -

```
Generic detail view Detail must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the view that you are using place_id in the URL, and that this maps to the place_id field on the model which should be used to lookup the Map.

```
class Detail(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    template_name = "detail.html"
    model = Map
    context_object_name = 'map'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'place_id'
    slug_field = 'place_id'
```